# JS lexing---multi line string

Tags: javascript, parsing, compiler-construction, interpreter, lex

I am making a JS lexer as part of my study. In JS, single line stings start from " or ' and ends with the same character except if that character is preceded by a backslash.

In my current code, I loop through every character and append them to existing tokens based on flags like "string" or "regex". so it feels natural to implement multi line string with " or ' because it seems that it does not affect any other part of my lexer

Is there any practical reason why new line is not allowed as contents of strings?

Comment: A newline is allowed in `'`/`"` strings as long as you escape it with a backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many languages, but not all, prohibit unescaped newlines in string literals. So JavaScript is certainly not unique here.

But the motivation really has little to do with the ease, difficulty or efficiency of lexical analysis. In fact, for lexical analysis the simplest syntax is to allow any character rather than having to include special-case checks. [Note 1]

There are other considerations, though; notably, the importance of a program to be readable and easy to debug. Long strings put an extra load on someone reading the code, because they may not be aware that a section of program text is actually part of a string literal. (There's a similar problem with multiline comments, which is why it's usually considered good style to mark every line in a long comment in some way, for example with a vertical column of stars at the left-hand margin. No such solution exists for string literals, though.)

Also, unterminated multiline strings can be annoying to correct. If strings are cannot span lines, the error will be detected on the line containing the problem. But multiline strings might continue until the beginning of the next string, then triggering a syntax error when the contents of the next string are accidentally parsed as program text. Or worse, resulting in a completely incorrect parse of what was supposed to be program text, followed by another incorrect string literal starting where the second literal ends, and continuing from there.

That also makes it hard for developer tools, such as editors and syntax highlighters, to deal with program text as it is being typed.

In the end, you may or may not find these arguments compelling, and a language designer might have other aesthetic preferences as well. I can't really speak for the original designers of the JavaScript language, and neither of us can take a voyage in time to argue with them and maybe change their decision.

For better or worse, languages are designed according to particular subjective judgements, and if the language is successful these judgements become permanent features. They are things you have to accept if you are using a language and they're not usually worth obsessing about. You get used to them, or you find a different language to program in, with its own syntax quirks.

When you design your own language, you will need to resolve a large number of syntactic questions, and you will undoubtedly run into cases where the answer is not clearcut because there is no objectively correct unique solution. Whatever you do, someone will want to argue with you. Perhaps you can refer them to this answer.

---

#### Notes:

1. There is actually a historic reason for not allowing multiline string literals, which is much clearer but has been more or less irrelevant for several decades.

   Once Upon A Time, common filesystems considered text files to be linear arrays of *fixed-length lines* (often 80 character lines, matching a Hollerith card). One advantage of such a filesystem is that it could instantly navigate to a particular line number in a file, since all lines were the same length. But in any case, for systems where programs were entered on punched cards, the fixed length lines were just part of the environment.

   To make all lines the same length, lines needed to be filled out with space characters. This would obviously make multiline string literals awkward, and that's why C never allowed multiline string literals, instead relying on a syntactic feature where consecutive string literals are automatically concatenated into a single literal.

   In the end, fixed-line-length filesystems proved to be unpopular, and I don't think you're likley to run into one these days. But a careful reading of the C and Posix standards shows that such filesystems must still be usable by conforming implementations, with the consequence that a fully portable program must be prepared to deal with line length limits on output and trailing whitespace on input.

Answer (score -1):

There is also such syntax

```js
const string =
'line1\
line2\
line3'
```

Comment: I know this syntax exists. But is there any performance benefit for the lexer when using this syntax over the ones like ``?

Comment: they are different: `` - adds '\n' to the output, but '\ - does not

Comment: same with `` though. when you add \ before new line in ``, it also does not appear in the resulting string.

Comment: @Y.Yoshii Performance benefits for the lexer are irrelevant. That's simply how the language was designed initially, it is to suit the programmer. Notice also the the different string syntaxes were introduced in different language revisions.

Comment: Partly my fault here. My question was not clear enough. I am not interested in the existing syntaxes and exceptions, but why the language designer made it that way. I deleted the last line in my question to make it more clear.